# Absolute criterion for clustering

Tags: clustering

everyone. I am puzzled, when without having truth labels, is there exist an absolute measure for clustering, like correctness for classification, to evaluate the quality of a clustering result? That is, when I have a clustering result, how to evaluate its quality without other results to compare?

Answer (score 0):

There are many such quality criterions.

Pretty much every algorithm has its own. For example k-means minimizes the SSQ for the given k (if you do not constrain k, the optimum is 0, every point its own cluster).

However, **does an absolute criterion make sense?**

I doubt so. You never can blindly rely on a clustering result. There is too much that can go wrong, including failure to preprocess the data well.

Being an *explorative method*, clustering was successful if and only if  *you* as the user learned something new about your data. **Do not take the user out of the loop.** Clustering is a subjective technique, there is no objective quality to it.

Suggested reading:

> Estivill-Castro, Vladimir (20 June 2002). "**Why so many clustering algorithms** — A Position Paper". ACM SIGKDD Explorations Newsletter 4 (1): 65-75.

who noted that **clustering is in the eye of the beholder**

Comment: Since I have no labels, the external criterion are not useable. And those popular internal criterion, such as Partition (SC) index, Xie-beni (XB), Davies-bouldin (DB), are absolute values, and only when there are several clustering results are compared, one can know the minimum/maximum index value represents a optimal partition. So I still wonder, does there exist an index, whose value means probability, i.e., the value of "1" indicates a perfect result ? Is there an absolute standard for clustering, like correctness for classification, to evaluate the quality of a clustering result?

Comment: Again, **there is no such thing as a perfect result**. You really should read that reference. Internal criterions are *useless* IMHO.